# Spring Test Context Framework

Tags: spring, testing, junit

I have a project which using Test Context Framework.

I'm execute the test using Run As -> JUnit Test but it show `initializationError()`;

Stack trace :

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.buildRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml")
public class PoolRuleMappingDaoTest {

     @Autowired
     private PoolRuleDao poolRuleDao;

     public PoolRuleMappingDaoTest() {

     }

     @Before
     public void setup() {

     }

     @After
     public void tearDown() {

     }

     @Test
     public void getCountryTest() { 

     }      
}
```

How to run the test ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688395/nosuchfielderror-when-trying-to-run-a-junit-test-with-spring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you might be running against an unsupported version of JUnit.

What version of `spring-test` are you using?

What version of `junit` are you using?

FYI: Spring 2.5 requires JUnit 4.4; Spring 3.0 and higher require JUnit 4.5 or higher.