# GWTMockito UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: gwt, mocking, gwtmockito

I've done most of my GWT testing MVP-style, without testing widgets. I'd like to be able to build more complex widgets and test them well without using `GwtTestCase` (slow).

Out of curiosity, I tried an extremely simple test. Given a very simple widget a little like this (this isn't my exact class, just a simplified example):

```
public class MyWidget extends Composite {
    private TextBox boxOne, boxTwo;

    public MyWidget() {
        boxOne = new TextBox();
        boxTwo = new TextBox();
        VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
        panel.add( boxOne );
        panel.add( boxTwo );
        initWidget( panel );
    }

    public String[] getText() {
      return new String[] { boxOne.getText(), boxTwo.getText() }
    }
}
```

And I'm using a GWTMockito test a little like this:

```java
public class MyWidgetTest {

    private ConstantsWithLookup constants;
    private MyWidget widget;

    @Before
    public void createMocks() {
        GwtMockito.initMocks( this );
        constants = mock( ConstantsWithLookup.class );
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsInvalidByDefault() {
        widget = new MyWidget( constants ) {
            protected void initWidget(Widget w) {
                // Disarm for testing
              }
        };
        assertNotNull( widget );
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        GwtMockito.tearDown();
    }

}
```

I immediately get:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document.nativeGet()Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Document;
    at com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document.nativeGet(Native Method)
    at com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document.get(Document.java:46)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox.<init>(TextBox.java:78)
    at mypackage.MyWidget.<init>(MyWidget.java:linenumber)
    ... etc ...
```

You'll note I'm not using the test runner -- I tried to, but the project I'm testing this on is using JUnit 4.4, the test runner doesn't seem to work with JUnit 4.4. If I use the GwtMockitoTestRunner, I get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at com.google.gwtmockito.GwtMockitoTestRunner.<init>(GwtMockitoTestRunner.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Based on [another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688395/nosuchfielderror-when-trying-to-run-a-junit-test-with-spring), and a quick investigation, I'm inclined to believe this has to do with the version of JUnit in use on this project. GwtMockito uses `BlockJunit4ClassRunner`, which is marked @since 4.5.

So -- is this test the sort of thing that GWTMockito is supposed to help with? I'm totally new to GWTMockito, so it could easily be a simple misunderstanding, but I'd like to understand.

Can I use GWTMockito to test complex widgets that are built from smaller widgets using `Composite` / `IsWidget`? Shouldn't GWTMockito have helped me with this JSNI issue, or am I misreading something? Is it just because I'm not using the test runner?

Comment: Could you post the test that is failing? Are you sure you're using the `GwtMockitoTestRunner`?

Comment: Hi @Wiseman were you able to solve this problem>?

Comment: It's been too long for me to remember the specifics -- although I do know the project in question did not end up adopting GwtMockito. Whether that was because I didn't find something that satisfied me about `GwtMockito` or not is lost to the mists of time. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I see it, there are two possibilities:

1. You forgot to use the GwtMockito's JUnit runner:

   ```java
   @RunWith(GwtMockitoTestRunner.class)
   public class MyTest {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   You can setup GwtMockito in an [alternative way](https://github.com/google/gwtmockito#support-for-junit-3-and-other-tests-that-cant-use-custom-runners), if you need a custom runner for something else.
2. You are not using `GWT.create` to instantiate your widgets.

The first point is straightforward - this runner is required so that GwtMockito can do its "magic".

The second point requires an explanation: GwtMockito works by using GWT's [Deferred Binding](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html). Meaning, all the widgets you want automatically mocked by GwtMockito *must* be instantiated by a call to `GWT.create`. This is straightforward with UiBinder - internally, all the widgets defined in the UiBinder's template are instantiated with `GWT.create`, so you don't have to change anything to use it with GwtMockito. But if you aren't using UiBinder (or are `providing` your own instances of widgets), GwtMockito won't be able to work its magic unless you instantiate your widgets with `GWT.create`.

From [GwtMockito's documentation](https://github.com/google/gwtmockito#what-is-gwtmockito) (emphasis mine):

> GwtMockito solves this and other GWT-related testing problems by allowing you to call **GWT.create** from JUnit tests, **returning Mockito mocks**.

---

#### Update

I can verify that with JUnit 4.4, the runner is throwning the exception you mentioned. I've opened an [issue on GwtMockito's tracker](https://github.com/google/gwtmockito/issues/44) for this.

As for the test itself, I've managed to get it to work. As I mentioned before, GwtMockito works thanks to Deferred Binding. Meaning, your widgets have to be instantiated with `GWT.create` - the members too. That's GwtMockito's "way in" into your widget. If you just call `new TextBox()` it won't be able to substitute that with a mock.
If you change your MyWidget class to the following it will pass the test (notice the calls to `GWT.create`).

```java
public class MyWidget extends Composite {
    private TextBox boxOne, boxTwo;

    public MyWidget() {
        boxOne = GWT.create(TextBox.class);
        boxTwo = GWT.create(TextBox.class);
        VerticalPanel panel = GWT.create(VerticalPanel.class);
        panel.add( boxOne );
        panel.add( boxTwo );
        initWidget( panel );
    }

    public String[] getText() {
        return new String[] { boxOne.getText(), boxTwo.getText() };
    }
}
```

Knowing this, there are some options:

- always remember to instantiate all widgets in your composites with `GWT.create`
- expose them as package visible (the way you do in UiBinder) and assign them mocks (either created from `mock` or `GWT.create`) in your tests
- switch to UiBinder ;/

None seem too attractive, the first one seems the best in general.

Comment: I am using the alternative way (minus 'initWidget' block which doesn't make any sense to me, since that method isn't defined in the composite I'm testing). I may still be missing something important, of course. ;)

Comment: I'd say that's your problem - as the GWTMockito's doc say: "When instantiating a widget, the test must also subclass it and override initWidget with a no-op implementation, or else it will fail when this method attempts to call Javascript". The GwtMockitoTestRunner does this automatically for you (I still don't understand why you're not using it - it should work with JUnit 4.4). Could you post `MyWidget`'s source too?

Comment: For some reason, I felt like composite didn't define initWidget(), which clearly isn't true. I'll have to resurrect the test and try again, see if that solves the problem. I've included a simplified widget in my question, and added some clarity on the error I get with Junit v4.4 (something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688395/nosuchfielderror-when-trying-to-run-a-junit-test-with-spring, but I can get a real stack trace when I try again)

Comment: `initWidget` is one of the most important methods in `Composite` ;) Please try "disarming" it as per the docs and report back. As for the JUnit 4.4 - if could recreate the bug then you might submit it to GwtMockito's [issue tracker](https://github.com/google/gwtmockito/issues), since they claim to support JUnit 4, so I'd assume that should include 4.4 too...

Comment: Yeah, adding the initWidget() override doesn't change anything.

Comment: I'll try again based on your update, but you've already been extremely helpful, so I'll credit you with the answer based on what you've already put into this. :) I don't love any of the options you propose, but it's starting to seem like those are the ways to make GwtMockito work with a composite.